# Label won't align properly in Windows XP

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, label

When running the program in Windows Vista, 7 or 8, it'll work just fine, but if I run the program then it'll be tabbed in and look bad. I've tried finding out why it does this, but I can seem to figure out why. All the other labels have the exact same settings.

Windows 7:

[image: Labels in Windows 7]

Windows XP:

[image: Labels in Windows XP]

As you can see, the Processor name is tabbed in on Windows XP. Is there any reason why it does it or how I can fix it? The only thing I've ever been able to do  to overcome this is to have the program detect if it's Windows XP and use `cpuLabel.Location = new Point(x, y);` to move it manually.

Comment: Sure it's an alignment issue and not something in the string "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500k CPU @ 3.30GHz"? Could be unintentionally getting something you don't want like a tab character in that string in the XP VM. Check it in the debugger.

Comment: Wow, I feel kind of dumb - I wasn't expecting it to grab that extra space when getting the CPU ID. Since it didn't do it in other Windows OS's I figured that wasn't it. Thanks - I'll add that as the answer.

Comment: Also is this Win Forms or WPF? The answer could really depend on that too.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it wasn't trimming the string in Windows XP. I did `cpuLabel.Text = CPUID.Trim();` and after doing that it worked just fine.

Thanks @[Zach Smiith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2441379/zach-smith)